# Count how many checkbox have been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to check how many checkbox user has checked.

```
var empty_watch = $('#clocks').find('input.checkbox:checked').length;
```

This is used in form validation: if empty_watch is 0 then do not post form: user must choose at least one item (and there is not a default one).

HTML is the following:

```
<div id="clocks" class="sez-form">
<fieldset>
<legend> Orologi inclusi </legend>
<div class="percheckbox">
    <input class="clock" type="checkbox" value="1" name="orologio">Browser
</div>
<div class="percheckbox">
    <input class="clock" type="checkbox" value="2" name="orologio">Prototipo1
</div>
<div class="percheckbox">
    <input class="clock" type="checkbox" value="3" name="orologio">test FP
</div>
<br style="clear: both;">
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Even if I check all the checkboxes empty_watch is still 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The key question is: *when* are you checking `empty-watch`? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your find selector:

```
'input.checkbox:checked'
```

looks for an input with a class of 'checkbox'. You should be looking at the 'type' attribute of the element.

Instead try:

```
'input[type="checkbox"]:checked'
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was wrong in selecting the object. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific `:checkbox` pseudo selector. It does the same as `input[type=checkbox]`:

```
var empty_watch = $('#clocks').find(':checkbox:checked').length;
```

As you already target `#clock` then find, this will be pretty good speed-wise too.

You could reduce it slightly, to the following, *if* you know there are no other checkable inputs:

```
var empty_watch = $('#clocks').find(':checked').length;
```